# What type of google map is this?

Tags: html, google-maps, iframe

What kind of google map is embedded here http://anga.umbrella.al/one-page/#contact
it's not iframe and it looks different.

Comment: Its google maps using the javascript api.It provides a lot more functionality.Take a look at the documentation https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google Maps API may be the answer, look here:

https://developers.google.com/maps/tutorials/fundamentals/adding-a-google-map